# JS (jQuery): Randomly trigger-click 2 table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, random, triggers

Given this HTML:

```
<div id="TABLE1" class="tabs">
    <table>
        <tbody datasrc="Music">
            <tr id="randomid">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="foo">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="abcde">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="fghijk">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="lmnop">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="qwerty">lorem</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="TABLE_2" class="tabs">
    <table>
        <tbody datasrc="Music">
            <tr id="random5">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="farhaf">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="haerf">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="hagasdg">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="hrfafh">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="qwerty">lorem</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<div id="LASTTABLE" class="tabs">
    <table>
        <tbody datasrc="Music">
            <tr id="rtefdgag">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="wrtjfd">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="reaht">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="aggag">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="rthhre">lorem</tr>
            <tr id="argarg">lorem</tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**I am trying to trigger 2 `<tr>`'s from each table randomly.** I cant even thing of the way doing this.

Currently for my test I use:

```
$("#button").on('click', function () {
    $('#randomid').trigger('click')
})
```

but this trigger's only the first row from the first table.

So how can I:

1. When I press #button,
2. Get 2 random row's from each table, Trigger
3. click each row every 10 ms (so they have an order).

About the app:

It is a music player website. Each table has different style of music. Rock, Alternative, Jazz etc. There is a button 'randomly select music'). That button, will trigger 2 random tr's from each table so you end up with 2 jazz songs, 2 rock songs etc to be added to the playlist. The table looks something like this: http://dribbble.com/system/users/31916/screenshots/167289/k-dribble.png?1309036379 but those checkboxes are not actual checkboxes but images which change position on click to look and feel better than a checkbox and still act the same as a checkbox.

The user can trigger the 'checkbox' or choose a song by clicking anywhere on the row (logical), so the back-end is developed in a way to capture clicks anywhere on a row and not specificly the checkbox (thus I am not choosing to trigger those). I dont think there is a better solution that just trigger click randomly 2 row from each tble.

Support for IE8+.

Comment: What is your end goal? What exactly are you trying to achieve by randomly clicking on two table rows?

Comment: Yes because if you are trying to do some sort of animation or create dynamic content or what-have-you, there are better ways than trying to randomly simulate click events on random rows in random tables. If people know what your end goal is, they might be able to offer you a solution that is better that what you are trying.

Comment: It is a music player website. Each table has different style of music. Rock, Alternative, Jazz etc. There is a button 'randomly select music'). That button, will trigger 2 random tr's from each table so you end up with 2 jazz music, 2 rock music to be added to the playlist. The table looks something like this: http://dribbble.com/system/users/31916/screenshots/167289/k-dribble.png?1309036379 but those checkboxes are not actual checkboxes but images which change position on click to look and feel better than a checkbox and still act the same as a checkbox

Comment: The user can trigger the 'checkbox' or row from clicking anywhere on the row, so the back-end is developed in a way to capture clicks anywhere on a row, I dont there is a better solution that just trigger click randomly 2 row from each tble.

Comment: what browsers are you supporting? can you use css3? random nth-child call?

Comment: IE8+ thus I am using jQuery. I am using there is a random with javascript and using jQuery children and trigger I should be able to accomplish it. I just cant think of a way. I am not new to development

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my version below,

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/skram/kzG3A/3/)

**Note:** Below code has some demo code and redundant vars which you can clean up, but I am leaving it there as to make the code look clear and self explanatory.

```
$(function() {
    var $tables = $('table'); //gets the tree tables

    var mQ = []; //music queue
    var timer = null;
    $('button').click(function () {
        $('#result').html(''); //demo code
        var t = 0, $tr;
        var t1 = [];
        $tables.each(function () {
            $tr = $(this).find('tr');

            t1[0] = Math.floor(Math.random()*$tr.length);
            t1[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*$tr.length);

            while (t1[0] == t1[1]) { //To make sure not same row is selected
                t1[1] = Math.floor(Math.random()*$tr.length);
            }

            mQ.push($tr.get(t1[0]));
            mQ.push($tr.get(t1[1]));
        });

        timer = setInterval(function () {//Create timer to trigger click every 10ms
            if (mQ.length == 0) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                return false;
            }
            $(mQ.shift()).click().addClass('selected');            
        }, 10);
    });

    $('tr').click(function () {
        //do your magic
        $('#result').append(this.id + '<br />');
    });
});
```

Comment: @Vega I submit the answer just for curious.But your is the best.

Answer (score 3):

I would first suggest that you do this a different way, but if you're set on triggering the click events here's the general idea.

```
  $(".tab").each(function(){
        var count = $(this).children(tr).length;    
        var r1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*count); //Get a random number less than the total count of rows
        $(this).children('tr').eq(r1).trigger('click');//retrieve the nth (r1) item in the list and fire it's trigger event

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

> Updated with new code on Fiddle too

Maybe more like this? ...

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        $(".selected").removeClass("selected");

        $("table").each(function(i) {
            var irand = {
                a: Math.floor((Math.random()*($(this).find("tr").length)-1)+1),
                b: undefined
            };

            while (irand.b == irand.a || irand.b == undefined) {
                irand.b = Math.floor((Math.random()*($(this).find("tr").length)-1)+1);
            };

            console.log($(this).find("tr").filter(function(i) { return i == irand.a || i == irand.b }).addClass("selected"));
        });
    });
});​
```

## See working fiddle here ...

Comment: This won't actually work. It's so designed for my test case. I've mentioned what the app is, thus I have more than 3 tables (roughly about 40). That said, I will need to make up to rand40 which that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: are allt he tables the same tr length?

Comment: Nop. Not at all. Tables are music categories. Each category has roughly 100 songs. That said, some may have 110, other 87 other 158 etc.

Comment: updated fiddle, i think it fits exactly what you're looking for, "think"